# reactjs: 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' will not trigger componentDidUpdate()?

Tags: reactjs

I have set dangerouslySetInnerHTML to be 'this.state.content', and when 'state.content' changes, the UI did update. However, I found that componentDidUpdate() is not triggered. Though, I found componentWillUpdate() did be triggered, and I can observe the nextState from its argument list is correct.

Is this phenomenon normal?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not expected. If componentWillUpdate is executed, componentDidUpdate should be too (unless render throws an error). If you have a repro case where that's false, please file a bug.

Comment: sorry. my question is confusing. After careful checking, I found that the componentDidUpdate() did be triggered, thought the param 'prevState' is not set to be the current (or latest) state object, as I expected. But I think that is normal phenomenon though. Thank you for your reply. @BenAlpert

Comment: componentDidUpdate receives two parameters: prevProps and prevState.

Comment: yeah i know. i mean i didn't got confused that in componentDidUpdate(), prevState !== this.state  @BenAlpert